# neo4j 4.3.3 apoc.periodic.iterate uses only one core : How does param concurrency work?

Tags: neo4j, parallel-processing, neo4j-apoc

> tl;tr:
>
> `concurrency` works as intended and gives us real parallelism, but watchout for your JVM config in a docker environment

When looking at the [docs of apoc.periodic.iterate](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/) there is the param `concurrency`

The docs explain the param as following:

> number of concurrent tasks are generated when using parallel:true

So when running following Code (on a machine with 64 idle cores):

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "UNWIND range(1, 10) AS x RETURN x",
    "CALL apoc.util.sleep(1000) RETURN 0",
    {
      batchSize: 1,
      parallel: true,
      concurrency: 10
    }
 )
```

I would **expect a runtime of ~1 second. But i got 10 seconds**

My expectation is: We have 10 "batches". Each batch should sleep 1 seconds. All 10 batches should run parallel.

Is my expectation wrong or is Neo4j/apoc buggy?

I know there is a difference between "concurrency" and "parallelism". The neo4j docs are not really clear what is happening here and mixing the two terms in one function. So maybe we dont really have real parallelism with `apoc.periodic.iterate`? If we dont, is there an alternative to real parallelism (via cypher only)?

Thanks for any hints!

**UPDATE No1** Added logs:

This is what the logs show (level: debug)

```
2021-08-25 09:32:28.282+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] starting batching from `UNWIND range(1, 10) AS x RETURN x` operation using iteration `CALL apoc.util.sleep(1000) RETURN 0` in separate thread
2021-08-25 09:32:28.282+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] execute in batch no 1 batch size 
2021-08-25 09:32:28.283+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] execute in batch no 1 batch size 
2021-08-25 09:32:28.283+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] execute in batch no 1 batch size 
2021-08-25 09:32:28.283+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] execute in batch no 1 batch size 
2021-08-25 09:32:28.283+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] execute in batch no 1 batch size 
2021-08-25 09:32:28.283+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] execute in batch no 1 batch size 
2021-08-25 09:32:28.283+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] execute in batch no 1 batch size 
2021-08-25 09:32:28.283+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] execute in batch no 1 batch size 
2021-08-25 09:32:28.283+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] execute in batch no 1 batch size 
2021-08-25 09:32:28.283+0000 DEBUG [o.n.k.a.p.GlobalProcedures] execute in batch no 1 batch size
```

Result is

```
╒═════════╤═══════╤═══════════╤═════════════════════╤══════════════════╤═══════════════╤═════════╤═══════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════╤══════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"batches"│"total"│"timeTaken"│"committedOperations"│"failedOperations"│"failedBatches"│"retries"│"errorMessages"│"batch"                                           │"operations"                                      │"wasTerminated"│"failedParams"│"updateStatistics"                                                    │
╞═════════╪═══════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│10       │10     │10         │10                   │0                 │0              │0        │{}             │{"total":10,"committed":10,"failed":0,"errors":{}}│{"total":10,"committed":10,"failed":0,"errors":{}}│false          │{}            │{"nodesDeleted":0,"labelsAdded":0,"relationshipsCreated":0,"nodesCreat│
│         │       │           │                     │                  │               │         │               │                                                  │                                                  │               │              │ed":0,"propertiesSet":0,"relationshipsDeleted":0,"labelsRemoved":0}   │
└─────────┴───────┴───────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────┴───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────
```

**UPDATE No2** Found the reason and a hotfix:

I guess the issue comes from a weird behavior of the Java VM in combination with my k8s.

I created a java script inside my Neo4j Container:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() = " +
                Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    }
}
```

This script returned, that Java only sees 1 core:

```
root@neo4j02-prod-5476cd65ff-2wdgk:/tmp# java -cp . main.java
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() = 1
```

I could hotfix that with the jvm option `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=60`

```
root@neo4j02-prod-5476cd65ff-2wdgk:/tmp# java -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=60 -cp . main.java
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() = 60
```

This was the prove for me that the JVM in the default Neo4j docker image, can not provide the correct core count in certain cases.

For now i can hotfix this by passing a `NEO4J_dbms_jvm_additional=-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=60` as ENVvar to my neo4j container.

**The question now is there a non hardcoded solution to this?**

Comment: Have you checked your logs? (neo4j.log and debug.log) you can find if the algo is creating 10 threads there (it shows something like - algo name + number of thread)

Comment: No the logs just say, in one moment, that all the batches are worked on. but the resulting time shows otherwise. btw: The DB has 64 CPU Cores available

Comment: Oh just noted something. Why are you passing batchSize:1? You should definitely turn this up, like A LOT, maybe 100, 1000, 10000. Also default concurrency is 50, no need to set it lower

Comment: NoNoNo, that is wrong. Batch size is the number of objects taken from the top query. if would enter batchsize 10 i would definitly get only 1 thread